$\operatorname{cov}(\mathcal{M}) = \mathfrak{c}$ and empty interior
Suppose $\operatorname{cov}(\mathcal{M}) = \mathfrak{c}$, that is. union of less than continuum many meager subsets of $\Bbb R$
is not  $\Bbb R.$ I think the following is true but I can not see it why:
Let $D$ be a union of less than continuum many meager subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Dose $D$ has a nonempty interior ?


Did you mean to ask if $D$ always has empty interior?

Well, $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to any open interval, and the homeomorphism takes meager sets to meager sets. So if $D$ contains an open interval, that interval is the union of a small number of meager sets. Wouldn't the homeomorphism then allow you to write $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of a small number of meager sets?

@AlexKruckman, I meant under this assumption $\operatorname{cov}(\mathcal{M}) = \mathfrak{c}$,

@MihaHabič, Got it, Thank you.  I think it is better for others to write it as answer and I will vote to it

Suppose that $D=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}M_\alpha$ is the union of the meager sets $M_\alpha$ and that $\gamma<\mathfrak{c}$. Suppose also that $D$ contains a nonempty open interval $I$. The sets $M_\alpha\cap I$ are still meager, so we might as well assume that $D=I$. But note that $I$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and the homeomorphism takes meager sets to meager sets. Therefore $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by $\gamma$ many meager sets which contradicts the assumption about the covering number.

Good answer. Thank you again
